# Peewee Sqlite Auto Vacuum

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I can't set auto_vacuum option via peewee.

Run this snippet:

```
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import SqliteExtDatabase, Model, TextField, IntegerField, JSONField

db = SqliteExtDatabase('my_app.db', pragmas=(('cache_size', -1024 * 64), ('journal_mode', 'wal'), ('auto_vacuum', 1)))

class EventLog(Model):
     key = TextField()
     value = JSONField()
     class Meta:
         database = db

EventLog.create_table()
```

After that:

I've connected to sqlite database

```
sqlite3 my_app.db 
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> PRAGMA auto_vacuum;
0
sqlite> PRAGMA journal_mode;
wal
```

Why auto_vacuum variable doesn't change?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this snippet from the [sqlite Pragma doc](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) [emphasis added] explains what is happening

> The database connection can be changed between full and incremental
>   autovacuum mode at any time. **However, changing from "none" to "full"
>   or "incremental" can only occur when the database is new (no tables
>   have yet been created) or by running the VACUUM command.** To change
>   auto-vacuum modes, first use the auto_vacuum pragma to set the new
>   desired mode, then invoke the VACUUM command to reorganize the entire
>   database file. To change from "full" or "incremental" back to "none"
>   always requires running VACUUM even on an empty database.**

Comment: This is the reason.